# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at /node_modules/ag-grid-ng2/dist/agGridNg2.js:2

Tags: angular, ag-grid-ng2

using ag-grid-ng2 there is error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined  at /node_modules/ag-grid-ng2/dist/agGridNg2.js:2"

Comment: Have you added `@types/node` in your `tsconfig.json`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
 "types" : ["node"]
}
my tsconfig.json code . still getting the above error.